# print all columns in dask after a function call print( )

Tags: python, pandas, printing, dask

I called on the

```py
print(df.isna().sum().compute())
```

on my dask dataframe. The code worked and showed an output as expected. However, on the various online tutorials, getting starteds, and samples, the result showed a complete list but when I used and followed the same syntax used, it showed me this:

```
var1       39560
var2           0
var3      118665
var4           0
var5           0
        ...   
var55    6054144
var56     416086
var57      19780
var58      19780
var59    7972615
```

I would like to have the output show all my 59 variables.

Answer (score 0):

you can still use some of the pandas syntax and dask "respects" that. In pandas, we use the function pd.set_option("displa.max_rows", 59). this function calls to displays rows, in your case you have 59 variables, thus the 59 in the parenthesis, you should be able to get an output of all the variables.

For reference. Type it before you call your print.

```
pd.set_option("displa.max_rows", 59)
print(df.isna().sum().compute())
```

it just works.

Answer (score 0):

As another solution that doesn't modify `pandas` configs:

```py
print(*df.isna().sum().compute().items(), sep="\n")
```

If `.compute` is a heavy operation and is called repeatedly,
one might want to store it in a variable:

```py
result = df.isna().sum().compute()
print(*result.items(), sep="\n")
```